# FlashVars syntax problem

Tags: html, apache-flex, syntax, flashvars

I've got the following javascript writing HTML for FlexPlayer:

```
document.writeln("<object width=\"489\" height=\"414\" FlashVars=\""+videoSource+"\">");
document.writeln("<param name=FlashVars value='sourceUrl=videoSource'>");
```

I need to have `FlashVars="sourceUrl=videoSource"`; where videoSource is a variable which I get from PHP for the current video and sourceUrl is variable form the Flex player. Please repair the int he first row cause this FlashVars syntax is driving me mad.

Comment: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html

Comment: Thanks as I read i should use flashvars only in param tag and the value is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) as an easier way to embed your swf into your website.  It also has a very simple way to include parameters (flashvars) into your movie in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation).